# How to encode URL using php like browsers do

Tags: php, url, browser, urlencode

I have an URL like this

```
http://www.example.com/Data/image/office-dôn-sì-à.jpg
```

I want to copy that file to my server using **copy** function in php. So the first thing is to encode it to this (I think browsers do the same thing)

```
http://www.example.com/Data/image/office-d%C3%B4n-s%C3%AC-%C3%A0.jpg
```

But if I use function **urlencode**, full url will be encoded to

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FData%2Fimage%2Foffice-d%C3%B4n-s%C3%AC-%C3%A0.jpg
```

which is not an URL anymore and not what I want.

Any help?

Comment: Do you want to **downoad** a file from an other server to yours using HTTP wrapper? http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php - How do you get the URL?

Comment: The encoded ULR is copied from address bar in FF. I did change its host name due to privacy. I want to copy file using:     

`copy('http://www.example.com/Data/image/office-d%C3%B4n-s%C3%AC-%C3%A0.jpg', 'destination.jpg');`

Comment: If you are sure that only the last piece (the filename) will contain special characters you can use Russel's solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, the other answers here have largely ignored your post, it seems. Let's hope I have not done the same.

It seems to me that you only want to encode the basename? If that is true, this ad-hoc function should do the trick:

```
function encode_basename($url) {
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    $base = array_pop($url);

    return implode('/', $url) . '/' . urlencode($base);
}
//returns: http://www.example.com/Data/image/office-d%25C3%25B4n-s%25C3%25AC-%25C3%25A0.jpg
```

Comment: function encode_basename($url) {
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    $base = array_pop($url);

   return implode('/', $url) . '/' . rawurlencode($base);
}

Comment: This answer shouldn't be marked as accepted as it doesn't solve the question. As others pointed out, you cannot use `urlencode()` but `rawurlencode()`.

Comment: No difference. This basename-only solution was not an answer anyway. And in this case, urlencode and rawurlencode are the same issue.