# How to url-encode only non-ASCII symbols of URL in PHP, but leave reserved symbols un-encoded?

Tags: php, utf-8, urlencode

I have a URL that looks like this (note the “„ symbols):

`http://tinklarastis.omnitel.lt/kokius-aptarnavimo-kanalus-klientui-siulo-„omnitel“-1494`

I receive it from SimplePie parser, if that matters. Now, if you try going to this specific URL in your browser and copy it from the address bar, you would get a URL that has the non-ASCII symbols [percent encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_unreserved_characters):

`http://tinklarastis.omnitel.lt/kokius-aptarnavimo-kanalus-klientui-siulo-%E2%80%9Eomnitel%E2%80%9C-1494`

I am trying to understand how can I mimic the same conversion in PHP. I cannot simply use [`urlencode()`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or [`urlrawencode()`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) as they encode both non-ASCII symbols **and** reserved symbols, while in my case the reserved symbols (/?&, etc) should stay as they are.

So far I have only seen [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441667/how-to-encode-url-using-php-like-browsers-do) that involve splitting the URL into pieces between reserved symbols and then using `urlencode()`, but that feels hackish to me and I hope there's a more elegant solution. I have tried various variations of `iconv()`, `mb_convert_encoding()`, yet with no success yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode URL using php like browsers do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441667/how-to-encode-url-using-php-like-browsers-do)

Comment: What's so "hackish" in the solution you linked to? What's that "elegant" way of the trivial string manipulation you are looking for?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I might be wrong, but for me it looks like my situation is not a arbitrary string manipulation exercise. Rather, it is a rather generic encoding task - the fact that browsers do that while copying URLs from address bar indicates that there should be some standard / meaning behind it.

Comment: Yes, this is generic encoding task. Which itself being trivial string manipulation. And you already have the solution. I see no point in posting another question if you already found the answer.

Comment: I am looking for a defined way to solve this task. In order to escape HTML, one can use htmlspecialchars() or just write a custom function with character codes & str_replace(). You are right, I know the custom way, but I am looking for a solution that would use in-built string manipulation functions (no matter how trivial they are).

Comment: You have it. the accepted answer in the question you linked to fits the description - it is using built-in string manipulation functions. What is your problem with it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have a simple one-liner that I use to do in-place encoding only on non-ASCII characters using preg_match_callback:

```php
preg_replace_callback('/[^\x20-\x7f]/', function($match) {
    return urlencode($match[0]);
}, $url);
```

Note that the anonymous function is only supported in PHP 5.3+.

Comment: **This should be the accepted answer.** It handles non-ASCII chars anywhere in the URL (path **and** query string), and does not need to perform checks such as "avoid double encoding" as in the OP's answer.

Comment: Good solution, thanks! If you also want standard-whitespaces to be encoded to `+`, use `'/[^\x21-\x7f]/'` instead. And if you want them to be encoded to `%20` to be compliant to RFC 3986, call `rawurlencode()` instead of `urlencode()`.

Answer (score 12):

After researching a bit, I came to a conclusion that there's no way to do nicely in PHP (however, other languages like python / perl do seem to have functions exactly for this use case). This is the function I came up with (ensures encoding of path fragment of the URL):

```
function url_path_encode($url) {
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    if (strpos($path,'%') !== false) return $url; //avoid double encoding
    else {
        $encoded_path = array_map('urlencode', explode('/', $path));
        return str_replace($path, implode('/', $encoded_path), $url);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This function may help:

```
function sanitizeUrl($url)
{
    $chars = '$-_.+!*\'(),{}|\\^~[]`<>#%";/?:@&=';
    $pattern = '~[^a-z0-9' . preg_quote($chars, '~') . ']+~iu';

    $callback = create_function('$matches', 'return urlencode($matches[0]);');

    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $url);
}
```

Comment: Allowed in url chars only: '-._~:/?#[]@!$&\'()*+,;='

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want.

```
<?php

$string = 'http://tinklarastis.omnitel.lt/kokius-aptarnavimo-kanalus-klientui-siulo-„omnitel“-1494/?foo=bar&fizz=buzz';

var_dump(filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH));
```

This will get you:

```
$ php test.php
string(140) "http://tinklarastis.omnitel.lt/kokius-aptarnavimo-kanalus-klientui-siulo-&#226;&#128;&#158;omnitel&#226;&#128;&#156;-1494/?foo=bar&fizz=buzz"
```

Comment: Good propose but it will not match  RFC 3986

Answer (score 0):

```
function cyrillicaToUrlencode($text){
return $line = preg_replace_callback('/([а-яё])/ui',
                            function ($matches) {
                                return urlencode($matches[0]);
                            }, 
                            $text); 
}

echo cyrillicaToUrlencode("https://test.com/Москваёtext1Воронежtext2Москваёtext3yМоскваё___-Москваё");
```

Will return - https://test.com/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%91text1%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6text2%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%91text3y%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%91___-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%91