# How to encode utf8 as url like browser does in PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8, urlencode

When entering this url into the Browser: `http://www.google.com/?q=ä`

The sent url is actually `http://www.google.com/?q=%C3%A4`

I want to do the same conversion using Php - how to do that?

What I tried:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com/?q=ä'; //utf8 encoded

echo rawurlencode($url);
//gives http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%3Fq%3D%C3%A4

$u = parse_url($url);
echo $url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'].$url['path'].'?'.rawurlencode($url['query']);
//gives http://www.google.com/?q%3D%C3%A4
```

The above url ist just a simple example, I need a generic solution that also works with

```
http://www.example.com/ä
http://www.example.com/ä?foo=ä&bar=ö
http://www.example.com/Περιβάλλον?abc=Περιβάλλον
```

The answer provided here is not generic enough:
[How to encode URL using php like browsers do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441667/how-to-encode-url-using-php-like-browsers-do)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: I have not tried it out yet, but this approach seems to provide what you are searching: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929584/encodeuri-in-php

Comment: Lixas: thanks but No. Please read the question.

Comment: I corrected my answer. Tell me if it's what you're looking for.. :)

Comment: Try this http://pastebin.com/b7LKuE8m

Comment: The linked duplicate is not php specific and doesn't contain a answer on "how" to do it.

Answer (score 14):

Ok, took me some time, but I think I have the universal solution:

```
function safe_urlencode($txt){
  // Skip all URL reserved characters plus dot, dash, underscore and tilde..
  $result = preg_replace_callback("/[^-\._~:\/\?#\\[\\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]+/",
    function ($match) {
      // ..and encode the rest!  
      return rawurlencode($match[0]);
    }, $txt);
  return ($result);
}
```

Basically it splits the string using *URL reserved characters* (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) + *some more* characters (because I think the "dot" should be also left alone) and does **rawurlencode()** on the rest.

```
echo safe_urlencode("https://www.google.com/?q=ä");
// http://www.google.com/?q=%C3%A4

echo safe_urlencode("https://www.example.com/Περιβάλλον?abc=Περιβάλλον");
// http://www.example.com/%CE%A0%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%B2%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%BD?abc=%CE%A0%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%B2%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%BD
// ^ This is some funky stuff, but it should be right
```

Comment: still looks like a universal solution in 2020. this is indeed very helpful.

Comment: _After all these years...? - Always..._ (in 2021 now)

Answer (score -1):

Looks that you want encode the `query` part of the URI without modify schema and host.

**Preamble**

There are no generic functions shipped by the language to achieve that because is not possible for the language to know if you will use the encoded string for a `redirect` or as `query argument` (?url=http%3A%3A....)

So the developer have to extract the part to encode as you did.

**Answer**

Encapsulate your own code as a function.

```
function encodeUrlQuery($url) {
  $u = parse_url($url);
  return $u['scheme'].'://'.$u['host'].$u['path'].'?'.rawurlencode($u['query']);
}

echo encodeUrl('http://www.google.com/?q=ä');
```

Comment: As I've stated in the question I have tried that and it doesn't do what I need

Comment: No. I see an example encoding query part and asking for a generic solution. Did you read the preamble of my answer?

Comment: Yes, so it's not a answer to my question :D